# Why do I keep getting these two errors?

Tags: python, int

I was doing a 7 kyu coding challenge from codewars.com, and while doing that I got this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "new.py", line 10, in <module>
    series_sum(5)
  File "new.py", line 3, in series_sum
    if "." in n:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

for this code:

```
def series_sum(n):
    str(n)
    if "." in n:
        n=n[:index('.')]+'00'
    elif '.' not in n:
        n = n+'.00'
series_sum(5)
```

Can someone explain why please?

Comment: `str(n)` returns  a string, it does not mutate `n`. `if "." in n` (probably) tries to iterate over an integer `n`.

Comment: Try: `n = str(n)` instead. Note that `series_sum(5)` has no effect as it does not return, output, or mutate anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify it that way:

```
def series_sum(n):
    n = str(n)
    if "." in n:
        n=n[:index('.')]+'00'
    elif '.' not in n:
        n = n+'.00'
series_sum(5)
```